# How can I put a Certificate into Google Earth?

Tags: certificate, google-earth

Through experimentation, I have found that I can connect to services requiring a Certificate, using Google Earth. However, I cannot find out how to get Google Earth to actually use a certificate. The pop up dialog box doesn't have an option of "Add Certificate."

Anyone know how I can give Google Earth a certificate to use to connect to a server?

Comment: What do you mean by "give Google Earth a certificate", what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Earth uses the Microsoft Certificate store for its certificates. Install your Client Certificate in either Google Chrome or Internet Explorer (both of which use the Microsoft Certificate store) and you Google Earth will be able to find and use the certificate. Please note however that Google introduced an issue in Google Earth version 5.2 and later related to HTTPS network links and certificates. Download/Install and use Google Earth v5.1 which can be downloaded [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_earth/download/d35fffc6f8851939035a279f6a7caffe) and all will be well.